# How to show "switch user" screen after Windows-L?

Tags: windows-7, hotkeys

When one locks the PC using Windows-L it activates a screen which shows account name and the text 'Locked'. There is also a "Switch User" button which open user selection screen.

What I would like to, is show directly the user selection screen when one locks the PC. This was easy to do with XP but how can it be achieved on Seven?

Comment: Which version of window's 7? Is it joined to a domain? My W7-Enterprise on a domain has a "Switch User" button when I lock the screen.

Comment: W7 Ultimate. It's not on a domain. As I wrote, there is a button, but I want Windows to show the switch screen without clicking any buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Win+L is a system assigned hotkey and there's no option to disable it. This means there's no way for an application to detect it, unless you use a low-level global keyboard hook (WH_KEYBOARD_LL).

More information at this SO post here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301053/re-assign-override-hotkey-win-l-to-lock-windows

The workaround would be to create a shortcut on your desktop that points to the User Selection page and assign a different hotkey to it:

1. Create a new shortcut on your desktop
2. Paste the following path in the Location box: C:\Windows\System32\tsdiscon.exe
3. After creating the shortcut, right-click the new shortcut and select Properties
4. In the Shortcut key box, enter a keyboard shortcut
5. Click OK
6. Test the results

Comment: Thanks!

I really hate it that they changed the behavior. I'll have to copy the shortcut now to all users.

Comment: You can copy a shortcut into C:\Users\Public\Desktop, this will automatically put it on every user's desktop

Answer (score 0):

My queries on this issue (I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate) resulted in a general consensus of "it's how Windows uses that shortcut, it can't be changed".

It's been a few weeks since I was searching, so maybe something new has turned up, but so far as I know you can't change that behavior.

I'll wait for people to prove me wrong now....